# Transition from mysql to postgress error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I wanted to change from mysql to postgresql.
I don't care about data so I have changed database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.postgresql

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.postgresql

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.postgresql
```

And run

```
rails db:reset db:migrate
```

But I get error

```
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have restarted both IDE (using c9) and server, but it gave no effect.
Any idea how to solve that problem?

@Edit After running `sudo service postgresql start` servers starts, and then when I run `rails db:create`

I get error:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
```

Comment: The postgres server is not running. If you are on a Mac, use http://postgresapp.com/ to download, install and run Postgres locally.

Comment: Check if postgres service is running, if is a different pc check port and firewall

Comment: Did you install the correct gem?

Comment: Guys, as I said, I am using C9. I think it works on ubuntu. I can't really do any of these things you said there.

Comment: I have installed gem 'pg', '0.19.0'

Comment: you can't address to postgres like you are handling sqlite3 db file. username, host and password also should be included. and i don't think posgresql allows slashes as db name.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in your terminal :

```
$ cd /usr/local/var/postgres/
$ rm postmaster.pid
```

It's because last time your computer was shut off, Postgresql did not exit gracefully (usually due to running out of battery).